# Stop IGraphicsContainer delete Refresh Automatically

Tags: arcobjects

Below is my code where I am first collecting graphic elements to delete, and then iterating the list to delete the elements. Issue is that the ArcGIS gets refreshed after every delete graphContainer.DeleteElement(item). How can I prevent it for automated refresh.

```c#
  IActiveView activeView = pMxDoc.ActiveView;
  IPageLayout pageLayout = activeView as IPageLayout;
  IGraphicsContainer graphContainer = pageLayout as IGraphicsContainer;
  graphContainer.Reset();
  IElement pElement;
  List<IElement> toDel = new List<IElement>();
  pElement = graphContainer.Next();   
  while (pElement != null)
  {
    //if (pElement is ITextElement)
    if (pElement is IMapFrame)
    {          
    }
    else
    {
      toDel.Add(pElement);        
    }
    pElement = graphContainer.Next();
  }
  foreach (IElement item in toDel)
  {
    graphContainer.DeleteElement(item);
  }
```

Comment: You should wire the IActiveViewEvents.ItemDeleted Event. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IActiveViewEvents_ItemDeleted.htm From there you can control what happens, whether a refresh, partial refresh, or nothing. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#8dbe2ce3-f2cc-497e-8a6f-b89ab93d1373.htm

Answer (score 2):

You should wire the IActiveViewEvents.ItemDeleted Event.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IActiveViewEvents_ItemDeleted.htm

From there you can control what happens, whether a refresh, partial refresh, or nothing.

For help on wiring events:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#8dbe2ce3-f2cc-497e-8a6f-b89ab93d1373.htm

Comment: Hi.

I added and Wired the Event Handler and here is where I am catching it. I used Partial Refresh, and also left every thing Blank. But it is still Refresh.

private void OnActiveViewEventsItemDeleted(object Item)
    {
      // Add your code here
      //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ItemDeleted");

      mpMxDoc.ActiveView.PartialRefresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewNone, null, null);      
    }

Answer (score 0):

I tired following and has worked for me.

I set the DelayUpdateContents property on IMxDocument and it has done the trick !

mpMxDoc.DelayUpdateContents = true;

Thanks for all the replies.

Hussain